# How to reuse existing NSManagedObjectContext after return from app being placed in background

Tags: core-data, ios7.1, magicalrecord-2.2

When a user places my iPad app in the background so he can use another app, then when done with the other app, returns to my app (running in the foreground), the previous MagicalRecord *defaultContext* is not restored (it is nil).

To fix this, my thought was to place the *defaultContext* in a Singleton, and restore it from there upon returning from the background or should I just create a new *defaultContext* as I originally did when the app started (in AppDelegate)?

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Managed object contexts are essentially transactions. It's fine to discard them and create new ones - discarding them of course will discard any unsaved changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is NOT to do a MR_cleanup (which I was doing) which resets everything; MR automatically retains the default context when the app resumes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `NSManagaedObjectContext` in the `appDelegate` and call it from the viewController using

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```